# Vortex image effect in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, image-processing

Kindly share if someone still has a copy of the Vortex image effect referenced here

https://docs.huihoo.com/unity/5.4/Documentation/en/Manual/script-Vortex.html

OR suggest an alternate way of achieving this effect in Unity exactly as described in the image link

NOTE: Effect is [Vortex](https://docs.huihoo.com/unity/5.4/Documentation/en/Manual/script-Vortex.html), not [Twirl](https://docs.unity3d.com/355/Documentation/Components/script-TwirlEffect.html). As I need a rotation of the image in the middle/specified area of the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can create such effects using Shadergraph.
Thre are some great tutorials on Youtube that could help you with it.